# Quickly, Treeview and Treestore, entry text not showing

Tags: application-development, quickly, glade

If I append entries to `treestore`, I can see that the entries are there, but I cannot see any of the text for those entries. I do not know if I have to add a `repaint` or something, or if I should link the `treestore` columns to the `treeview` columns some way.

The problem (no text is displayed):

[image]

Columns added to `treeview`:

[image]

and the code I added to add entries to the tree:

```
# Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
treestore = self.builder.get_object("treestore1")

root = treestore.append(None,["from_test1","to_test1"])
treestore.append(root,["from_test2","to_test2"])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second screenshot, the `Tree View Editor`, you should right click each column you want to show text in and select `Add child text` to add a `Gtk.CellRendererText` to this column.
The first property for the cellrenderer should be a value from the liststore you want to show in that column.

Same goes for a `PixBuf`, `Spinner`, `Progress`, etc columns.

[image: Defining the treemodel columns]
[image: Creating and linking to the cellrenderer]